# LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS AVONA in SPARK mllib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib, anova

I'm using LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS (mllib) in Scala. How can I get the  analysis of variance (ANOVA) of the model?